# Redirect subfolder request to Passenger

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, passenger

I want to redirect all requests like `mysite.com/subfolder/...` to Django application over Passenger and all other requests to the website running under some php cms.

File structure:

- .htaccess
- subfolder/

  - .htaccess
- some cms files

Content of root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

... RewriteConds and RewriteRules generated by php cms
```

Content of `subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
PassengerAppRoot "/home/username/djangoapplication"
PassengerPython "/home/username/virtualenv/webapp/2.7/bin/python2.7"
```

The problem is about root `.htaccess`. When root `.htaccess` is empty (constails only `RewriteEngine on`) requests like `mysite.com/subfolder/...` are handled by `subfolder/.htaccess` and Django application loads. But when root `.htaccess` contains lines generated by php cms all requests like `mysite.com/subfolder/...` leads to the 404 error page from cms.

So I want to filter requests like `mysite.com/subfolder/...` to `subfolder/.htaccess` before `RewriteRule`s from cms will replace it with 404 error page, but I can't figure it out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the root `.htaccess` file only contains mod_rewrite directives then you can completely override the root `.htaccess` file by simply enabling the rewrite engine in `/subfolder/.htaccess`.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On    

PassengerAppRoot "/home/username/djangoapplication"
PassengerPython "/home/username/virtualenv/webapp/2.7/bin/python2.7"
```

By default, mod_rewrite directives are *not* inherited by default (unlike other modules). However, it is possible that mod_rewrite inheritance has been specifically enabled in your server config, so this may not work.

If this doesn't work then you would need to create an exception at the top of the root `.htaccess` file, that prevents requests for the `/subfolder/` being overridden. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder - [L]
```

This stops any further processing in the root `.htaccess` file when the URL starts with `/subfolder`.

Comment: Thank you! mod_rewrite was always black box written by aliens for me.