# Django project on cpanel, www.example.com is working but www.example.com/admin or www.example.com/aboutus gives 404

Tags: python-3.x, django, cpanel

I have created Django project on godaddy cpanel shared hosting ,

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is working and everything working fine with images and html templates, but when I hit [www.example.com/about](http://www.example.com/about) or [www.example.com/admin](http://www.example.com/admin) or any other url it gives 404.

here is my passenger_wsgi.py file

```
import website.wsgi
SCRIPT_NAME = '/home/udpo***j0so4/website'
class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib.parse import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME

        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
application = website.wsgi.application
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

here is my settings.py file

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '****************'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.example.com','example.com']



INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'home',
'django_user_agents',
'django_filters',

'django.contrib.sites',#django-allauth
'allauth', #django-allauth
'allauth.account', #django-allauth
'allauth.socialaccount',#django-allauth
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google', #django-allauth
 ]


MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  ]

 ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

  TEMPLATES = [
   {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
       },
       },
       ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


    DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'database',  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'user',  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'password',  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '166.**.**.**',  # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '3306',  # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
   }
   }


  AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
   {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
   },
   {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
   },
   {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
  },
   {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
   },
    ]


   LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

   TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

   USE_I18N = True

   USE_L10N = True

  USE_TZ = True

  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR + '/assets',]
  STATIC_ROOT = '/home/udpo***vj0so4/public_html/assets'
  MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/udpo****vj0so4/public_html/media'
```

and here is my urls.py files

```
            from django.contrib import admin
        from django.urls import path,include
        
        urlpatterns = [
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
            path('', include('home.urls')),
            path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
        ]
```

and app urls.py files

```
from django.urls import path,include,re_path
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import reverse
urlpatterns = [
            path('aboutus/', views.intro, name='ab'),
            path('frequent_questions/', views.fr_ques, name='fr_ques'),
            re_path(r'^search=(?P<query>.+)$', views.search, name='search'),
            path('Contact_us/', views.contact_view, name="contact"),
            path('', views.home_1, name='homee'),

        ]
        
        urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I tried this solutions also but not worked for me.

[Django 1.11 on passenger_wsgi not routing POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594955/django-1-11-on-passenger-wsgi-not-routing-post-request/50827230#50827230)

[Can't login to admin site. Returns a page not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028254/cant-login-to-admin-site-returns-a-page-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

I tried every possible solution but not any of them worked.

Than I changed to hosting provider and than it worked.

So i thought that it might be the hosting issue and i tried different godaddy hosting server from Asia to America and it also works for America Server.

Here I talked almost more than 3 days to godaddy's support team but they don't have knowledge possible reasons of this issue.

Answer (score -2):

Check your root folder .htacces I added "RewriteEngine On" at the begging as  pointed out in:

[Redirect subfolder request to Passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044204/redirect-subfolder-request-to-passenger)

and it worked